# ¿Es correcta esta validación de direcciones de correo electrónico con expresiones regulares?

Tags: javascript, regex

Esta es la expresion regular que quisiera saber si está bien, es para validar emails:

```
 var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9-_\.])+\@([a-z])+\.([a-z]{3})$/
```

La probé con emails como estos:

```
xiheye@promaild.com,
correo.de-prueba_@mail.com
```

Comment: Puedes probarlo tu mismo por ejemplo en esta [web](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta es.. la probaste? tuviste algun problema usandola? asi como esta, la pregunta se responde con un simple si o no y no ayuda mucho.

Comment: Define "bien", por lo que veo dominios que terminen en .es o .ar no serían válidos porque esperas siempre 3 caracteres tras el punto

Comment: Lo siento, soy nuevo en la comunidad, intentaré hacer lo que dices gbianchi

Comment: Hola @Daniflow323 por favor evita los saludos en tu pregunta y en el título y trata por favor de colocar uno (título) que de indicio del problema expuesto

Comment: En este caso, en las preguntas sobre regex, ademas se espera varios ejemplos de cadenas que son validas, y cadenas que son invalidas. No sabemos si micorreo@pp.com es valido.. o si micorreo@pp es valido.. o cual es cual..

Comment: Como dominio puede haber ip's también mira esto https://emailregex.com/